# Regular expression, match anything not enclosed in

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

Given the string foobarbarbarfoobar, I want to have everything between foo. So I used this expression for that and the result is: barbarbar. It's working great.

```
(?<=foo).*(?=foo)
```

Now I also want the opposite. So given the string foobarbarbarfoobar I want everything that is not enclosed by foo. I tried the following regular expression:

```
(?<!foo).*(?!foo)
```

I expected bar as result but instead it returns a match for foobarbarbarfoobar. It doesn't make sense to me. What am I missing?

The explanation from: https://regex101.com/ looks good to me?

```
(?<!foo).*(?!foo)
(?<!foo) Negative Lookbehind - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
foo matches the characters foo literally (case sensitive)
.* matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible,    giving back as needed [greedy]
(?!foo) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
foo matches the characters foo literally (case sensitive)
```

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for it:

```
^((?!foo).)+
```

Explanation from regex101

> `^` assert position at start of the string
>   **1st Capturing group** `((?!foo).)+` 
>   Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
>   **Note**: *A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data*
>   `(?!foo)` Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below 
>   `foo` matches the characters foo literally (case sensitive)
>   `.` matches any character (except newline)

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping someone finds a better approach, but this abomination may do what you want:
`(.*)foo(?<=foo).*(?=foo)foo(.*)`

The text before the first foo is in capture group 1 (with your provided example this would be empty) and after is in capture group 2 (would be 'bar' in this case)

If you want the 'foo's included on either end, use this instead: `(.*)(?<=foo).*(?=foo)(.*)`. This would result in 'foo' in group 1, and 'foobar' in group 2.